# Python: access class properties as array

Tags: python, arrays, class

Originally i'd like to make a class that has a few string and float properties, one being a timestamp in float format. having a list of ~10'000 instances of that class i'd like use those 10'000 timestamps as if I had a numpy array for math operations of vectors:

```
import random
import time

class myclass:
def __init__(self):

    # some properties
    self.ID=random.random()
    self.text1 = 'sometext'
    self.text2 = 'some other text'
    self.timestamp=time.time()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    for i in range(10):
        mylist.append(myclass())

    # now apply math functions to the timestamps, for example 
    # max([all timestamps]) or sum([all timestamps])
```

I could just have a row in an array instead of a class instance, but then many advantages (not shown here) of using classes are lost.

Can you help me?

Comment: You are going to have to implement this interface yourself

Comment: Did you try something? What was the problem? This can be trivially done like `max(x.timestamp for x in mylist)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `operator.attrgetter` to create a callable for the timestamp; use it with `map` *on* the list of instances; consume the map object with `sum` or `max`.

```
from operator import attrgetter
tstamp = attrgetter('timestamp')
print(sum(map(tstamp, mylist)))
print(max(map(tstamp, mylist)))
```

Comment: Does this have any advantages over ``max(map(lambda x: x.timestamp, mylist))``?

Comment: I would say that the only advantage would be that you can *define* the callable once and assign it to a meaningful name then use it anywhere in your module. That's why I like to use `operator.whatever`'s.